# What is the best way to download large amount of data and save it without locking the phone (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project (JAVA), but i need to download many line of a database from a server like 3.5K lines , my questions is - what is the best way to download large data without letting the phone become slow , because i used Retrofit and also XmlAsyncTask  , but cos of the data to download are much , as I download each time the phone almost crashes,

despite the fact that i used background threads. so what is the best way to do to avoid the phone crash with eavy data.

Thanks.

Comment: So why does it crash then? There should be a stacktrace that you can analyze.

Comment: I made a test and wrote a code which is run on runOnUiThread , i change the value of a TextView , but i think may be cos of the number of the data to download , the textview doesn't change until all data are download before the textview values update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are receiving to much data in one request, this data is stored in memory before it can saved in another source and this is the reason that block your phone. The way to use retrofit and background thread is the correct, so you only have to manage the way that you are receiving the data, get it in small amounts recursively and store it in a physical source. I suggest RXJava or Kotlin Coroutines for this kind of operations because is easier and works very well together.
I hope that it works for you. 
Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i think i will finally follow your advices and send the data progressively

Answer (score 0):

In any scenario you should contemplate a reconstruction scenario. 
In that case, you maintain the request alive? 
Maybe you can divide a huge request into a small and successive requests...

Comment: Thanks a lot , i think i will finally follow your advices and send the data progressively

Comment: Congratulations, always think about reconstruction on Android develops, because is a condition scenario!